# Mocking external hardwares

Tags: .net, mocking, device

How can I mock external devices that are connected to my c# 4.0 .NET application? Is there a particular framework that will make it easier?
I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: I would suggest a google search first as a quick one comes up with one or two possible answers for you

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you can make your life easier by putting something between your program and the hardware. For example, say you had hardware that switches a fridge on and off:

```
public class Fridge {

    public void SwitchOn() {
        // Call Fridge Hardware
    }

    public void SwitchOff() {
        // Call Fridge Hardware
    }
}
```

You can then extract an interface from this class, like so:

```
public interface IPoweredAppliance {
    void SwitchOn();
    void SwitchOff();
}
```

And now you can rely on `IPoweredAppliance` in your program, supplying an instance of the `Fridge` class for "real life" and supplying a test double in your tests.

You'll need to explicitly implement the interface as C# is nominally typed...

```
public class Fridge : IPoweredAppliance {
```

You can write the test-double manually, or you can use a mocking framework, which will create one based on the interface, which is often easier.

Any mocking framework will be pretty easy... Rhino Mocks, MOQ, NMock2 - I prefer Rhino myself but the others are good too.

Comment: might be good to show that Fridge implements IPoweredAppliance